# Is Garfiel Tinsel named after Garfield the cat?

Tags: re-zero

Garfiel Tinsel is capable of transforming into a cat (or rather, a tiger). I couldn't help but notice his name is similar to Garfield, a famous comic strip cat. Was his name chosen as an homage to this character? And is the reason he goes on a rampage so often because it's Monday and there's no lasagna? Or are any similarities just coincidence?

[image: Garfield]

[image: Garfiel Tinsel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just one of many nods to other animated series, novels and folklore you'll find throughout Re:Zero.  There are many scattered throughout the web novel and some don't even make it into the light novel or anime.  Most are much more subtle than Garfiel and very easy to miss.  One other notable reference from the anime is the ringtone music that plays on Subaru's phone which is from "The Dog of Flanders" series. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fvPkdlPgMw

Edit: Actually, the Dog of Flanders series is also where the name Patrasche comes from. (Pronounced "Pah-tra-shay", Like Patricia).

To be honest, there are certainly more references to the stars and celestial bodies than references to other animated series, but I'm guessing that is because the stars are much more relevant to the main story.